# CSS mix-blend-mode not working with text and background image

Tags: css, colors, background, mix-blend-mode

In my new project, I want to use `mix-blend-mode: difference` for my logo (top center) but it is not working.

[See project](https://kommerzialisiert.de)

In CSS, I used this:

```
.sitetitle-txt-inner span {
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent `.sitetitle-txt-inner` is empty and transparent.

Try adding different background colors for the `<div>` and `<span>` and you'll see blending is working.

---

Result of red and blue:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but what I wanna do is, that the title mixes up with the background image. As you can see [here](http://thirtyfive.tv/about). So a colored background seems not the right way

Comment: Try adding the image as background of `.sitetitle-txt-inner`. I don't think this feature works with ancestor elements further up

Comment: There are many sites like [this](https://billybultheel.pro/html/angst.html) where whole text passages have this mix-blend-mode without any background-image.